# Is palm oil bad for health?

Tags: nutrition

Lately, Russian TV and various internet sites have started a campaign against palm oil (Пальмовое масло).

Here are some examples:

- [Пальмовое масло: вредно или полезно?](http://www.domashniy.ru/zdorovoe-pitanie-i-diety/palmovoe_maslo_vredno_ili_polezno/) [Trans: *Palm Oil: Harmful or Helpful?*]
- [Вред пальмового масла для здоровья человека](http://www.vashaibolit.ru/795-vred-palmovogo-masla-dlya-zdorovya-cheloveka.html) [Trans: *Palm oil is harmful to human health*]
- [Анна ГЕРАСИМЕНКО, Анна КУКАРЦЕВАAa
  В Госдуме заинтересовались: опасно ли для здоровья россиян пальмовое масло](http://www.spb.kp.ru/daily/26248.4/3128731/) [Trans: *The State Duma is interested in whether Palm Oil is dangerous to Russian's health]
- ["Нераскрытые тайны": Чем опасно пальмовое масло](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPBjf7VsoNA) [Video, Trans: *"Unsolved Mysteries": The dangerous palm oil*]

Some of the common health effect claims of Palm oil consumption are:

- increased risk of heart diseases
- obesity
- atherosclerosis
- thrombosis

Though there are more claims, I just have come across these most often.

Comment: Yes, give links. Because there are thousands of them, it should be easy. We need to know what health effects are claimed because it is too broad right now.

Comment: @Oddthinking - from link #1, TL;DR seems to be linked to high levels of saturated fat (palmine acid, not quite sure what the actual molecule is called in English)

Comment: @Oddthinking, I added some links. Health effects claimed vary from article to article, I smell they just making it up, but usually they just talk about it being bad for veins, not completely digested, increasing heart diseases risk, etc. The problem is it all seems to be some kind of mass media hoax or something, it really smells like completely made up stuff(much like with GMO and MSG)

Comment: @Oddthinking - there's mentions of cancirogenic effects. Plus, lack (only 5%) of "good" Linoleic acid

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have tidied up the text. Note that it still isn't a great question [because of the issues discussed here](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/is-is-this-foodstuff-harmful-harmful/3481#3481)

Comment: @Oddthinking, thanks. I may fix the question based on this later(stating the diseases). Maybe even answer it, I am starting to find some credible info & statistics. But tomorrow, too tired now.

Comment: I wonder how many of these "harmful effects" apply to any vegetable oil and not palm oil in particular.

Comment: @phillip if that claim is notable, you can write a separate question for it.

Comment: I am certain you can find on the web credible assessments of the "badness" of various vegetable oils.

Comment: As compared to other vegetable oils, Palm Oil has a particularly high percentage of saturated fat (as does coconut oil).  They're probably better compared to other mostly-saturated fats, rather than other vegetable oils.